# How does unsigned subtraction work when it wraps around?

Tags: c

This is a macro in the lwIP source code:

```
#define TCP_SEQ_LT(a,b)     ((int32_t)((uint32_t)(a) - (uint32_t)(b)) < 0)
```

Which is used to check if a TCP sequence number is less than another, taking into account when the sequence numbers wrap around. It exploits the fact that arithmetic wraps around, but I am unable to understand how this works in this particular case.

Can anyone explain what happens and why the above works ?

Comment: Work it out with, eg, an 8-bit number.

Comment: I so want to make a compiler that converts out-of-range numbers to 17 when the target type is signed.

Comment: @DanielFischer As long as you document it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Sure, that's a requirement. But who reads the documentation?

Comment: @DanielFischer If I was going to do this, I would make `char` unsigned, first because why stop at one unusual implementation-defined choice, and second because standard library prototypes more or less imply that you can interconvert between `char` and `unsigned char` without data loss. `fgetc()` returns an `unsigned char` value in an `int`, whereas string.h functions take pointers to `char` for strings.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes, and logical right shift for negative integers. Basically, break all common assumptions about implementation-defined behaviour. If your programme still produces the expected results, bully for you.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sounds like you want to invent the [DS9K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:CompuHacker/CHDS9000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a simple 4 bit integer example where a = 5 and b = 6. The binary representation of each will be

```
a = 0101
b = 0110
```

Now when we subtract these (or take two's complement of b, sum with a, and add 1), we get the following

```
0101
1001
+  1
-----
1111
```

1111 is equal to 15 (unsigned) or -1 (signed, again translated using two's complement). By casting the two numbers to unsigned, we ensure that if b > a, the difference between the two is going to be a large unsigned number and have it's highest bit set. When translating this large unsigned number into its signed counterpart we will always get a negative number due to the set MSB.

As nos pointed out, when a sequence number wraps around from the max unsigned value back to the min, the macro will also return that the max value is < min using the above arithmetic, hence its usefulness.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it would be e.g. a=14 and b=1 , which should yield that a is less than b (or similar, for demonstrating the wrapping case).

Comment: When I code this up in practice, I see negative values when a = 0->b, but also after the difference between the two values is greater than 127 (using two unsigned chars for a and b in my case).  This would inaccurately report that if b = 64 and a = 192 that a is less than b.  This would be true for a == 192 -> 63.  Can you clarify more here? @ryanbwork

Answer (score 0):

Because it is first cast as a signed integer before it is compared to zero. Remember that the first bit reading from left to right determines the sign in a signed number but is used to increase the unsigned int's range by an extra bit.

Example: let's say you have a 4 bit unsigned number. This would mean 1001 is 17. But as a signed integer this would be -1.

Now lets say we did b0010 - b0100. This ends up with b1110. Unsigned this is 14, and signed this is -6.

Answer (score 0):

On wrap-around a will be much greater than b. If we subtract them the result will also be very large, ie have its high-order bit set. If we then treat the result as a *signed* value the large difference will turn into a negative number, less than 0.

If you had 2 sequence numbers 2G apart it wouldn't work, but that's not going to happen.